# How android reminder app works after closing it

Tags: android, background-process

I want to create an reminder app on android. How it works after closing the app? Thank you.

Comment: idk what have you tried to do?

Comment: Mostly magic. Oh and Android APIs.

Comment: for more information of reminder app you can download the fabulous on play store..

Comment: Try learning and using android background service app. this link may help you https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

Comment: and you can use also set foreground and background service like boot_complete: for restart device..

Comment: Thank you to all for your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its called **services**. You can run process in background once you get permission from user.

please learn more about services from here:

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: You don't need permission to run a service